# CORS with SignedURL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

***How can I use the SignedURL returned from the Go API with CORS?***

CURRENT SETUP:

**Bucket config**

`gsutil cors get gs://example-bucket`

returns:

```
[{
  "maxAgeSeconds": 1, 
  "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "PUT", "DELETE", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
  "origin": ["http://example.com", "https://example.com", "http://localhost:4000"], 
  "responseHeader": ["Origin", "Accept", "X-Requested-With", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "Content-Length", "Accept-Encoding", "X-CSRF-Token"
]}]
```

**Go API call**

```
acc, _ := appengine.ServiceAccount(ctx)

signedUrl, err := storage.SignedURL(
        "example-bucket",
        fileName,
        &storage.SignedURLOptions{
            GoogleAccessID: acc,
            SignBytes: func(b []byte) ([]byte, error) {
                _, signedBytes, signingError := appengine.SignBytes(ctx, b)
                return signedBytes, signingError
            },
            Method:      "PUT",
            ContentType: contentType,
            Expires:     time.Now().Add(1 * time.Hour),
        })
```

**JS XHR**

Uses the SignedURL from Go, i.e. `xhr.open("PUT", signedUrl);`

**EXTRA NOTES**

The SignedURL is generated by the Go API always starts with `https://storage.googleapis.com/example-bucket/fileName`... elsewhere I've read that it should be `www.googleapis.com/storage` but I don't think this is the problem, surely the url returned from the official API is correct.

I can see that the request headers include:

- `access-control-request-headers: content-type,x-upload-content-type`
- `access-control-request-method: PUT`
- `origin: http://localhost:4000`

So it seems it ticks off all the boxes of the required header...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the JS side, I was setting additional metadata for the file uploads via the `X-Upload-Content-Type` header.

Since this header was not in the CORS config, requests were failing.

By adding that header into the config (e.g. the `responseHeader` list supplied to `gsutil cors set` config file), everything is working exactly as described in the question :)